# Upgrading a 13" 2009 Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, processor, motherboard

So, I have a 13" 2009 Macbook Pro that I've upgraded as far as I can go without changing the motherboard/processor (8 GB RAM/2 SSDs). My question is, since the unibody case is the same, is there anything stopping me, other than common decency, from getting a replacement motherboard and processor from a newer model and throwing it into my 2009 vintage MBP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You'll have a real issue with the airport/bluetooth cable as well as the position and length of the LVDS cable.  Besides, you will gain very little as the newest revision of this was 2012 and the improvements are very small compared to the cost of a logic board.